# Multiple math value from one query

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a problem with one query.

```
SELECT
        CASE WHEN b.value IS NULL 
        THEN sum(d.value)
        ELSE sum(d.value) + sum(b.value)
        END AS sumaWydatkow

        FROM data d
        LEFT JOIN data_bills b 
        ON  d.id = b.data_id
        WHERE   d.type = 0

        UNION

        SELECT

        CASE WHEN b.value IS NULL 
        THEN sum(d.value)
        ELSE sum(d.value) + sum(b.value)
        END AS sumaPrzychodow

        FROM data d
        LEFT JOIN data_bills b 
        ON  d.id = b.data_id
        WHERE   d.type = 1
```

I want to sum two column or if one of them (data_bills) is empty, sum only one table, with two version of column type, 0 and 1.

But now is a one clumn with two records. I want two column with one for each.
I'm asking if that could done with one query ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't entirely follow.  Perhaps some sample data and desired results would help to illustrate your problem?

Comment: Want to sum two columns. This columns are on two diffrent tables. But I want to do that with one QUERY. With UNION, I have one coolumn in results with two records of QUERY. But I want to have a output result in two columns, with one record per column :) Thanks for replay

Comment: Perhaps some **sample data** and **desired results** would help to illustrate your problem?

Comment: An SQL Fiddle example would be helpful: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
      ( SELECT
        CASE WHEN b.value IS NULL 
        THEN sum(d.value)
        ELSE sum(d.value) + sum(b.value)
        END AS sumaWydatkow

        FROM data d
        LEFT JOIN data_bills b 
        ON  d.id = b.data_id
        WHERE   d.type = 0
       ) type0,

      ( SELECT
        CASE WHEN b.value IS NULL 
        THEN sum(d.value)
        ELSE sum(d.value) + sum(b.value)
        END AS sumaPrzychodow

        FROM data d
        LEFT JOIN data_bills b 
        ON  d.id = b.data_id
        WHERE   d.type = 1
      ) type1
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ec52/2

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this:

```
CASE WHEN b.value IS NULL 
    THEN sum(d.value)
    ELSE sum(d.value) + sum(b.value)
    END
```

?  That's going to base whether to include sum(b.value) on some arbitrary row's b.value.  You probably mean just: `sum(d.value) + coalesce(sum(b.value),0)`
(Saying `CASE WHEN sum(b.value) IS NULL...` would be equivalent.)

I would do it this way (thanks for the fiddle, kordirko):

```
SELECT
    sum( if(d.type=0, coalesce(d.value,0)+coalesce(b.value,0), null) ) type0,
    sum( if(d.type=1, coalesce(d.value,0)+coalesce(b.value,0), null) ) type1
FROM data d
LEFT JOIN data_bills b
ON  d.id = b.data_id
WHERE d.type in (0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT   d.type, SUM(d.value) + SUM(b.value)
FROM     data d LEFT JOIN data_bills b ON b.data_id = d.id
WHERE    d.type IN (0,1)
GROUP BY d.type
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ec52/9/0) (again, with [thanks to @kordirko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481398)).